# Archiving a one-to-one relationship in Ecto

Tags: database, elixir, ecto

I have two models: `Actor` and `Room`. This is just a minimal example.

```
# `Actor` Model

defmodule MyApp.Actor

use Ecto.Schema
  schema "actors" do
    field :actor_name, :string
    field :status, Ecto.Enum, values: [:Active, :Archived]
    belongs_to :room, Room
  end
end


# `Room Model`

defmodule MyApp.Room

use Ecto.Schema
  schema "rooms" do
    field :room_number, :integer
    has_one :actor, Actor
  end
end
```

I want to model a one-to-one relationship i.e. A `Room` can have only one `Actor` at a given time. An `Actor` can come and leave a `Room`. What I want is that when an `Actor` leaves a `Room`, I still want to retain the reference to its previous `Room` relationship for archival purposes. In my case, an `Actor` is created immediately before it occupies a room, and then it has to be "archived" after leaving the room. Additionally, I have the field `Actor.status` to help me with my "archival" tasks.

Currently, if I add to the `Room` relationship for my `Actor` using `%Room{} |> Ecto.build_assoc(:actor, %{actor_name: "Test"})`, the relevant Actor is created with right pointer to the right Room; however, Room instance will always point to the first Actor object that was added to it.

If I use `put_assoc`, it fails due to foreign key constraints (and that of course makes sense because I have defaul behavior for `:on_delete`)

**My constraint**:

1. I want to be able to access the current/ most recent Actor that was `build_assoc` with a `Room` by something like `some_room.actor` and likewise `some_actor.room`. (At this point other dependencies rely on this architecture).
2. Ideally I stay within one-to-one association. One possible solution for me would be to add another column and manually manage it to map to it's original `Room` association when detaching from its `Room` and do some trickery when I do `some_actor.room` since this will fail for the old `Actor`s.

Comment: If I were to switch to `has_many` then this post does guide me in the right direction: https://elixirforum.com/t/ecto-and-preloading-most-recent-record-from-association/520

Comment: `"actors"` schema should use `has_one :room, Room` instead of `belongs_to :room, Room`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I don't think that's correct. OP states "when an Actor leaves a Room, I still want to retain the reference to its previous Room relationship for archival purposes". So Actor needs to have a `room_id`. That's my impression of how this works.

Comment: @PeacefulJames I do not see any issue keeping `room_id`.